# Change Label by value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, buddypress

I have a BuddyPress profile form that currently has fields being shared between different member types, so they can be forced to be mandatory.

I would like field A (highlighted) to be able to change the labels/legends highlighted with B, so that once a user selects a value I can show the relevant text (which needs to change for each drop down value)

[image: Label change per context]

I already have PHP code to control these labels AFTER the user has selected a member type, I just need to know what to before hand, before they save these values.

The first field is field_6.

The second is field_19
The third is field_505
The fourth is field_56

I believe a javascript piece of code would make this work appropriately, but is not my strong suit programming language wise.

UPDATE:

The requirements have since changed, but I have found the solution, and sharing for others to use. This also includes changing labels on an input box as well.
If anyone has a better way of writing this code, happy to take advice

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field_6').change(
        function () {

            var membertype = $('option:selected', this).text();
    var cphmtp = document.getElementsByClassName("field_56");
    var cphmtp_label = cphmtp[0].getElementsByTagName("label");
    var age_ranges = document.getElementsByClassName("field_505");
    var age_ranges_legend = age_ranges[0].getElementsByTagName("legend");
    var age_ranges_option = document.getElementById("field_1120_0");
            if (membertype == 'Babysitter or Nanny') {
$("#field_56").val("");
cphmtp_label[0].innerHTML = "Cost Per Hour  (required)";
$('.field_56').show();
age_ranges_legend[0].innerHTML = "Age ranges of children able to sit    (required)";
$("label[for='field_1120_0']").html('<input type="checkbox" name="field_505[]" id="field_1121_0" value="I don\'t mind">I don\'t mind');
$('.field_505').show();
            } else if (membertype == 'Parent') {
$("#field_56").val("1");
$('.field_56').hide();
age_ranges_legend[0].innerHTML = "Age that my children are  (required)";
$("label[for='field_1120_0']").html('<input type="checkbox" name="field_505[]" id="field_1121_0" value="I don\'t mind">I\'d rather not say');
$('.field_505').show();
            } else {
$('.field_56').hide();
$('.field_505').hide();
}
        });
 });
```

Comment: You want the label values or the values in the field?

Comment: please show the html you coded .

Comment: I am after the label values, not the values in the fields, the labels themselves have those values. I have not written any code so far, as I am not sure where to start in regards to this.  IE I want to change the label Cost Per Hour to another value if the user select Parent.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your questions !

Comment: anyone know an answer to this?? I know it's going to be javascript